# How to check for a confirmation email and then reading it in python

Tags: python, selenium, email, bots

I want to check for new emails and then opening it when it arrives in my python script. I'm new to python. This would be a part of a bot that signs up and then clicks the confirmation link in the email. There is no need to check if the sender is right, because I am sure there will be no other emails coming. I know how to search for the link in the email and opening it. The problem is waiting for the email and when it arrives, continuing with the script. Thank you in advance.

This is how my code looked like before. (Without the waiting)

```
import poplib
import re
import webbrowser


def getmail():
    M = poplib.POP3("server")
    M.user("user")
    M.pass_("password")

    numMessages = len(M.list()[1])
    whole = ""
    for i in range(numMessages):
        for j in M.retr(i+1)[1]:
            whole += j

    result = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", whole).group("url")
    result = result[:-1]

    chrome_path = 'open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s'
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(result)
```

I know this code is ugly and messy and probably stupid, so if you have any suggestions about that too, I would be thankfull.

Comment: you might consider using a webmail interface for this... (if you can)  That way you can still use the Selenium framework to check... run a loop that checks for date greater than the time you clicked the button to send confirmation and then checks for a (hopefully) unique subject line.  You can just catch no such element and re-run the method from the catch. (with a sanity count to determine if sending failed.) Hopefully the page you are testing also provides some feedback if the e-mail send fails or succeeds.

Comment: I have no idea where to begin coding. What libraries should I use? An you reffer me to any docs?

Comment: Selenium is all you will need and you'll need to tailor it to fit each each site and webmail client.  I would avoid gmail, btw, as I think it will detect you as a bot and not allow you to login.